# How to communicate between an activity and a service by calling each others methods?

Tags: android

This ***is*** a duplicate, but whatever I try I can't find the answer any more.

What I want to do is to call a (local) service from an activity, so that the service can record sensor data and transfer those to the activity, but only if the activity is active.

There are at least a dozen near duplicates asking that, and I had found but lost an answer that solved it in a way appropriate for my project.

The service registered any calling activity (that had to implement a special interface) in a list, and then went into a loop, calling a "doUpdate" method of each registered activity instance.

I forgot and can't figure out any more on how exactly the service retrieves the activity instance.